Directionally closing an image using opencv morphology or otherwise
I'm trying to use opencv morphology to close a binary image. However I would like to close along the maximum intensity direction locally rather than the entire surrounding region. The idea is for me to use the binary image that is created after this operation to extract a skeleton.
The idea I have come up with so far is to use the hough line transform on a localised ROI of the image. then use the direction given by this transform to create a kernel that approximates the direction of this line. then use this kernel for the opencv close operation rather than the generic np.ones kernel. However this is quite computationally expensive and seems to give mixed results. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this. I'm fairly new to opencv so your thoughts and comments are highly appreciated.
Thank you!
Original image -> [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Z46bJxfm.jpg
Binary image generated using k-means clustering -> [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/H3TNekkO.jpg

I have seen lots of 1-rep users upload images. They appear as links in the post, but they're still uploaded to the official image repository.

Your question is quite difficult to follow. When you say "close an image", I assume you want to apply a closing operator to the image. You're dealing with a binary image, but refer to the "maximum intensity direction", which make it seem you have a grayscale image as well? I assume that your problem is that your image binarization operation leaves gaps in the binary image. Instead of filling them in after the fact, you should try to fix the binarization operation.

[mre] required. we need to see something tangible. prose isn't tangible. -- Hough is a newbie trap. Maslov's Hammer. you don't necessarily need to suggest an approach if you're new to a field.

Thanks for your comments!! I misunderstood the reputation requirements. The images are up now.
@CrisLuengo: You are correct. I do start with a grayscale image that has gaps as you say. And these then show up in the binary image as well. By "maximum intensity direction" I mean that there is a line along which the moment of the pixel intensities would be the least even if they are binary intensities.

Is this the best input image quality that you can provide? Please provide some code that exactly shows where you got stuck!

Nice question, but your approach may not be the best one. What is your end goal here ? Maybe you can reach it with another approach. Because for a closing operation with a dynamically changing kernel i can only think of writing a custom and  very poorly optimized code.
